# Can't upload files on a mamp server\

Tags: php, html, macos, file-upload, mamp

I wrote a simple html to upload file on server by a simple php script.
On windows, on a xampp server it works well, because I know perfectly the path where the files are going to be uploaded (c:\xampp).
On mac I tried many times, viewing, copying and pasting the path obtained in the finder... I have something like applications/mamp/htdocs but I doesn't work...
Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot.
Franz

Comment: You can find all the information about uploaded files in the $_FILES super global variable. It includes the full path to the uploaded files.  Have you seen this: **[information about processing uploaded files in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)**.

Comment: If you want to know what PHP thinks of the 'environment' is running in, then run 'phpInfo()' in any 'internet facing' script. It will tell you a lot including 'upload' tmp dir. Remove the phpInfo command after you have finished with it. It is rather useful to 'naughty persons'.